# how to store data using mongoid and rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, mongoid

I am new to Rails and mongo. I am trying to build a simple blog page where a post can contain many comments.
Post Controller is where i have problem. I don't know how to store and retrieve comments for a post that had been already published.

Post model

```
class Post
 include Mongoid::Document
 field :title, :type => String
 field :body, :type => String
 has_many :comments
end
```

Comment model

```
class Comment
 include Mongoid::Document
 field :content, :type => String
 belongs_to :post
end
```

Current Post controller can save posts but not comment.

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController

  def show

@post = Post.find(params[:id])
@comment=Comment.new
respond_to do |format|
  format.html # show.html.erb
  format.xml  { render :xml => @post }
end

end

def new
  @post = Post.new

  respond_to do |format|
  format.html # new.html.erb
  format.xml  { render :xml => @post }
 end
end

def create
@post = Post.new(params[:post])

respond_to do |format|
  if @post.save
    format.html { redirect_to(@post, :notice => 'Post was successfully created.') }
    format.xml  { render :xml => @post, :status => :created, :location => @post }
  else
    format.html { render :action => "new" }
    format.xml  { render :xml => @post.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mongoid provides accessors for your relations, in this case

```
posts.comments
posts.comments = [ Comment.new ]
comment.post
comment.post = Post.new
post.comments << Comment.new
post.comments.push(Comment.new)
...
```

Please see, http://mongoid.org/docs/relations/embedded/1-n.html

Here's a modified posts/show action.

```
  def show

    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    @comment = @post.comments.all.to_a
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.xml  { render :xml => @post }
    end

  end
```

Here's a new posts/comment action.

```
  def comment
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    comment = Comment.create(params[:comment])
    @post.comments << comment
    @comment = @post.comments.all.to_a

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { render :action => "show" }
      format.xml  { render :xml => @post }
    end
  end
```

app/views/posts/show.html.erb

```
<pre>
Post
  <%= @post.inspect %>
Comments
  <%= @comment.inspect %>
</pre>
```

tests/functional/posts_controller_test.rb

```
require 'test_helper'

class PostsControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase

  def setup
    Post.delete_all
    Comment.delete_all
    @param = {
        post: { title: 'Mongoid relations', body: 'The relation has auto-generated methods' },
        comment: { content: 'a piece of cake' }
    }
  end

  test "show" do
    post = Post.create(@param[:post])
    get :show, id: post.id
    assert_response(:success)
  end

  test "new" do
    get :new
    assert_response(:success)
  end

  test "create" do
    get :create, @param
    assert_response(:success)
  end

  test "comment" do
    post = Post.create(@param[:post])
    get :comment, { id: post.id }.merge(@param)
    assert_response(:success)
    assert_equal(1, Post.count)
    assert_equal(1, Comment.count)
    assert_equal(@param[:comment][:content], Post.first.comments.first.content)
  end

end
```